# How can I get rid of a blank page that appears me before my references?

Tags: bibliographies, blank-page

I'm using WinEdt 7. I would like to know how can I eliminate the blank page that appears before my references.  This is my code (.tex):

```
     \renewcommand{\bibname}{
       \clearpage\pagestyle{myheadings}%
        \markboth{}{}%
        \renewcommand{\bibname}{REFERENCIAS BIBLIOGRÁFICAS}%
        \setboolean{SetDSpace}{false}%
       \chapter*{\bibname}%
        \addcontentsline{toc}{extrachapter}{\bibname}%
        \setboolean{SetDSpace}{true}%
     }
```

The other code is in a. cls file but it doesn't displays well, I mean it doesn't displayed neither the title nor the link to the table of contents. So I created the above code and put it in the main .tex file. This is the .cls code:

```
\renewcommand{\bibname}{REFERENCIAS BIBLIOGR\'AFICAS}%
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]%
 {\renewcommand{\bibname}{REFERENCIAS BIBLIOGR\'AFICAS}%
 \clearpage\pagestyle{myheadings}%
  \markboth{}{}%
  \setboolean{SetDSpace}{false}%
  \chapter*{\bibname}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{extrachapter}{\bibname}%
  \setboolean{SetDSpace}{true}%
  \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
       {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
        \setlength{\parsep}{\BaseDiff\baselineskip}%
        \setlength{\itemsep}{0ex}%
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
        \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
        \@openbib@code
        \usecounter{enumiv}%
        \let\p@enumiv\@empty
        \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
  \sloppy
  \clubpenalty10000
  \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
  \widowpenalty10000%
  \sfcode`\.=1000\relax}
 {\def\@noitemerr
   {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
  \endlist\clearpage}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 3):

As I already answered to you [crosspost](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=23118) on [LaTeX-Community.org](http://latex-community.org/): the problem here is that you redefined `\bibname`, which is just for the name of the bibliography which goes into the heading. So `\chapter*{\bibname}` actually nests `\chapter*` calls: `\chapter*{...\chapter*{...}...}`. Only that you redefined `\bibname` again inside, prevents an infinite recursion.

Instead, redefine `thebibliography` similar to the class file. So, start your own code also with

```
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{%
...
```